# Jquery off click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this may sound like a silly questions but is there something I can call for offclick events for exmaple I have this currently;

```
$("#frame_left").click(function() {
    $("#navLeft").show();
});
```

I want to hide the `#navLeft` content once a user has clicked off of the radio button?

Comment: Otherwise known as `onmouseup`? or do you mean, clicking on anything that isn't the element or a child of the element.

Comment: What exactly does "click off of" mean? Choosing another radio button?

Comment: Give each of your radio buttons a class, register a `Click` event to that class and check if the desired radio button is selected?

Comment: you could either bind a click event to the container around the radio button to hide the navLeft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    $("#navLeft").hide();
});
```

And then be sure to prevent the event from propagating when clicking the `#frame_left` element:

```
$("#frame_left").click(function(e) {
    $("#navLeft").show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, and to everyone else that helped

Answer (score 5):

Add a click event for the entire document:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  $('#navLeft').hide();
});
```

Then stop propagation on the element, so it doesn't bubble up to the document:

```
$("#frame_left").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#navLeft").show();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: I have this so far already - 

          $(document).ready(function(){
            // do your checks of the radio buttons here and show/hide what you want to
            $("#navLeft").hide();
            $("#navRight").hide();
           
            // add functionality for the onclicks here
            $("#frame_left").click(function() {
              $("#navLeft").show();
            });

            $("#frame_right").click(function() {
              $("#navRight").show();
            });
          });
         </script>

Comment: That doesn't format in a comment. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net or add it to your original question.

Comment: @Nat read the answer more carefully. Blazemonger is telling you to use `$(document).click` not `$(document).ready` (although you should call `.click` inside of `.ready`)

Comment: +1 I didn't realize you could do `.click` on `document` but it seems cleaner than my answer.

Comment: I tried your example Blazemonger, but I have a few issues, one when you click anywhere outside the radio button the content that is shown disappears even though the radio button is still selected. Also If I set this up for more than one radio button if I click one option then change my mind and click another option it keeps both content displayed instead of hiding my first option and then showing the 2nd radio button i selected